# Why does one of my MouseListeners stop working when I add a new one?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

Below is a code example which might look awkward because it's only a small part of a bigger program. I wanted to add a MouseWheelListener so that I can use the mouseWheelMoved method to zoom in and out, which is located in the "Visualization" class. The good news is that the zooming actually works, but the problem is that my mouse dragging code in the "SomeTest" class stopped working once I added a MouseListener in the constructor of the Visualization class.

```
package sometest;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;

public class SomeTest implements Runnable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SomeTest st = new SomeTest();
        st.run();
    }  
    
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
        Visualization v = new Visualization();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(v);

        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() 
        {
            private Point origin;
            
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                origin = new Point(e.getPoint());
            }
             
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
            {
                JViewport vp = null;
                
                if (origin != null) 
                {
                    vp = sp.getViewport();
                }
                
                if (vp != null) 
                {
                    int deltaX = origin.x - e.getX();
                    int deltaY = origin.y - e.getY();

                    Rectangle view = vp.getViewRect();
                    view.x += deltaX;
                    view.y += deltaY;

                    v.scrollRectToVisible(view);
                }
            }
        };

        sp.getViewport().addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        sp.getViewport().addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
        
        f.add(sp);
        f.setContentPane(sp);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

```
package sometest;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
public class Visualization extends JPanel implements Scrollable, MouseWheelListener
{
    private double zoomFactor = 1;
    private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
    private boolean zoomer;
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    
    public Visualization()
    {
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        Font currentFont = getFont();
        Font newFont = currentFont.deriveFont(currentFont.getSize() * 15F);
        setFont(newFont);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        
         if(zoomer) 
         {
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

            double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
            double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();

            double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;

            xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
            yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;

            at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
            at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
            prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
            g2d.transform(at);
            zoomer = false;
        }
         
        g2d.drawString("1234567890", 500, 200);
            
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
    {
        zoomer = true;

        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) 
        {
            zoomFactor *= 1.1;
            repaint();
        }
        
        if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) 
        {
            zoomFactor /= 1.1;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
        {
            return new Dimension(2000, 800);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() 
        {
            return new Dimension(1550, 800);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) 
        {
            return 32;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) 
        {
            return 32;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() 
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() 
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

The desired result is that I want to be able to zoom in and out of my JScrollPane, but also be able to move through the JScrollPane by dragging my mouse. Did I implement the MouseListeners incorrectly, or is my problem something entirely different?

Comment: Have you tried using seperate mouse adapters?

Comment: @MouamleHasan I just tried that, but it still yields the same result. Zoom works, but dragging my mouse does not work.